# npm Install different folders with one script

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm, package.json

I want to run one `npm install` on the project root to install both server and client packages.

My project structure is:

```
project
│   package.json
|   node express files...
└───client
    │   package.json
    |   react app files...
```

And also, create one script that runs `npm run dev` on the root folder and `npm start` on the client folder.

I tried to use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently), and it does work for running the apps, but for installing, I get a weird infinite loop that keeps installing in the root folder:
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlnVy.png)

And I guess if concurrently is not globally installed, it wouldn't work anyway for the first installation.

package.json scripts in the root folder:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "dev-client": "cd client && npm start",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "install": "concurrently \"npm install\"  \"npm run install-client\"",
    "dev-both": "concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm run client-dev\""
  },
```

Any ideas how for a fix or an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid infinite loop, try this :

```
"both-install": "concurrently \"npm install\"  \"npm run install-client\"",
```

Answer (score 0):

to install client try this:

"install-client": "cd ../client && npm install",

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do the same thing. What I found is that don't use "install" in the "package.json" file. If you change it to another word, it will work fine. like **"install:all"** or **"both-install"** etc.

```
"install:all": "npm install && npm run install-client",
```

This will work fine. You didn't need to use "concurrently" or any external npm module for that purpose.
when you use "**install**" keywork in package.json then npm work command run again and agian.